# Pinescript v5 error with function request.security argument with expr type "float series"

Tags: pine-script

I'm going crazy trying to avoid an error in Pinescript v5:

```
MA = nz(AMA[1]) + 0.5*(hlc3 - nz(MA[1]))    
signal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, MA)
```

It returns undeclared identifier, but not if I type:

```
MA = hlc3    
signal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, MA)
```

Also gives an error if I type:

```
MA = 0    
MA = nz(AMA[1]) + 0.5*(hlc3 - nz(MA[1]))    
signal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, MA)
```

It returns "series int" declared when type "series float".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MA = nz(AMA[1]) + 0.5*(hlc3 - nz(MA[1]))    
signal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, MA)
```

Self referencing is not allowed.

You should write this as:

```
MA = 0.0
MA := nz(AMA[1]) + 0.5*(hlc3 - nz(MA[1]))    
signal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, MA)
```

Below statement makes `MA` an `int`.

```
MA = 0    
MA = nz(AMA[1]) + 0.5*(hlc3 - nz(MA[1]))
```

If you want to declare it as a `float` either do `MA = 0.0` or `flaot MA = 0`.

Also, please note that, you should use the `:=` assignment operator when you are assigning a value to an already declared variable.